# Login server web app java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hi I am writing a basic login server using message passing . What my server does is it receives the message from some client checks in the database which is a file and accordingly sends back the reply so what is happening is whenever I send the message from telnet i can see that my server is accepting it and replying to it but it is not accepting a message again. Below is my code and this is no homework

```
package login;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Login login = new Login();

        new Thread(login.new ServerTask(null)).start();
        new Thread(login.new ClientTask("clientstart")).start();
    }

    public String login(String userName, String password, String memberId) {
        System.out.println("Entering login");
        boolean match = false;
        try {

            // created an file input stream and a buffered reader stream to read
            // from the files
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/home/rahulroc18/Desktop/database.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String strLine;
            String[] dataReader;
            dataReader = new String[10];
            String readData = "";

            // Loop through the end of the file and read the data line by line
            // in order to store it into a string for further storage in the
            // memory

            while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                readData = readData + strLine + ":";

            }
            // split the string to store user name and password for storing in
            // an array in alternate positions

            dataReader = readData.split(":");
            // System.out.println(dataReader.length);

            // loops through the array and checks the user name and passwords
            // for
            // the correct match sends the login successful if password is
            // incorrect sends message password in correct else for no match
            // sends check your credentials

            for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.length; i++) {
                if (userName.equals(dataReader[i])) {
                    match = true;
                    if (password.equals(dataReader[i + 1])) {
                        String message;
                        message = "Login Successfull" + " : " + userName
                                + " : " + password + " : " + memberId;
                        System.out
                                .println("Sending success message to client !!!");
                        return message;
                        // send the transactions and data of whatever
                        // conversation has taken place till now
                        // System.out.println("for loop of login");
                        // System.out.println("message to be sent back is: " +
                        // message);
                        // new Thread(new ClientTask(message)).start();
                        // Send message to all users that this new user has
                        // joined the conversation
                        // System.out.println(message);

                    } else {
                        String message = "";
                        message = "Password Incorrect";
                        System.out.println("message to be sent back is: "
                                + message);
                        System.out.println(message);
                        return message;
                    }

                }
            }
            if (!match) {
                String message = "";
                message = "check your credentials";
                System.out.println("message to be sent back is: " + message);
                return message;
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }

        System.out.println("Exiting login");
        return null;
    }

    class ServerTask implements Runnable {

        String msgReceived;

        public ServerTask(String message) {
            msgReceived = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Server task started !!!");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10000);
                Socket clientSocket = null;

                while (true) {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    msgReceived = buffer.readLine();

                    if (msgReceived.substring(0, 5).equals("login")) {
                        System.out.println("in if condition of server task");
                        String finalMessage = login(
                                msgReceived.substring(5, 10),
                                msgReceived.substring(10, 15),
                                msgReceived.substring(15));

                        System.out.println("finalMessage is " + finalMessage);

                        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                        bw.write(finalMessage);
                        bw.flush();

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("************");
                        String message = "Client started successfully and startup message is recieved \n";

                        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                        bw.write(message);
                        bw.flush();

                    }
                }

            } catch (StreamCorruptedException sc) {
                System.out.println(sc);
            } catch (IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class ClientTask implements Runnable {
        String msgToSend;

        public ClientTask(String message) {

            msgToSend = message;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Socket sock = new Socket();
            try {

                sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10000);

                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        sock.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(out);

                buffer.write(msgToSend);
                buffer.flush();
                sock.close();
                System.out.println("In client task .... message is "
                        + msgToSend);

            } catch (SocketException s) {

            } catch (IOException i) {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't read all your code, but it looks like in `TaskServer.run` you never close any stream nor `clientSocket` when done.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains lots of bugs.

1. You have to create separate class for the client and the server.Now in your code what is        happening is that suppose what happen if your client thread will start first rather than the server thread.
2. `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` this will come in your main thread and whatever the object you receive from `serverSocket.accept();` will come as a parameter in other thread.So your server will wait for the request from client in main thread and your newly created thread will handle the client.

Comment: Hi Sahil,
I think making inner classes is not a problem you don't have to make separate classes if you are saying this for a specific reason please mention it and this code is working fine lemme update it with the latest code. It's just that it is accepting message for one time and sending the reply just one time it does not do it again and again